# ExifInterface returns 0

Tags: android, image, attributes, exif

I'm trying to get the image orientation using ExifInterface class but i always get 0.

Snippet:

```
ExifInterface ei;

try {
    ei = new ExifInterface("/storage/sdcard0/etp_images/31_demo2@gmail.com.jpg");
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    Log.v("ORIENTATION", String.valueOf(orientation));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I was looking many answers about this question but none has result me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i get the same 0 result although i want to fetch the gps location of my image. I think it is something wrong with the file location.

Answer (score 0):

The code written seems to be OK. Can you try to click few photos by rotating your phone in 90, 180 etc

Once you do this you will get orientation properly.

I think you were checking the images having same orientations